# Rounding error in density functions of R-programming language

Tags: r, rounding-error, log-likelihood, mpfr

Using R I am trying to compute the likelihoods of a vector of values. Some of these values are way off into the tails of the distributions. Rounding error appears to be causing the results to be rounded to zero, making my code throw an error when drawing samples.

I looked into using the Rmpfr package to get higher precision, but this changes my variable type. I also considered rewriting the expression into a log-form to avoid multiplication. Then the expression would become:
 `exp(log(w[X]) + dnorm(y, x[X], sigma[X], log = TRUE))`

This still causes the function to return a zero, due to the exponentiation.

Would there be a way to formulate this problem with logs, allowing for high numerical precision? What I want in the end is for the following probabilities to be correctly computed, summing to one.

```
  liks <- lapply(1:3, function(X) {
    w[X] * dnorm(y, x[X], sigma[X])
  })

  probs1 <- liks[[1]]/(liks[[1]] + liks[[2]] + liks[[3]])
  
  probs2 <- liks[[2]]/(liks[[1]] + liks[[2]] + liks[[3]])
  
  probs3 <- liks[[3]]/(liks[[1]] + liks[[2]] + liks[[3]])
```

**Edit: Adding Numerical Example of Log Code**

Here are some parameter and sample values that start throwing errors with the log-code. They do not throw NANs. Instead each of the three entries is zero:

```
$mu
[1] 0.7323412910 0.7742235621 0.4863889347

$w
[1] 0.008464 0.083536 0.908000

$sigma
[1] 0.08209500030 0.08166088502 0.09168991045

Observation values:
c(4.667935371,  5.654500961,  4.383309364,  4.396201611,  4.452524185,  4.441100597,  4.890487194,  4.416962624,  5.241273880,  4.347382069,  4.867616177,  4.895996094,  4.592288494, -3.612523079,  4.817468166,  4.783963203,  4.541391850,  4.709537983,  5.227987289,  5.585811138,  4.497674942,  4.989979267,  4.489729881)
```

All the observation values are rather extreme / outliers in my dataset. This would explain why they are assigned probabilities so small that they are rounded to zero.

Comment: Example of an extreme value becoming zero: 0.09554102 * dnorm(-3.612523, 0.8133402, 0.03580487)

Comment: Why do you need to exponentiate? Avoid that.

Comment: @Roland I would rather avoid it, but then the computations of the probabilities make no sense anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with logs throughout, don't take the exponential so soon.  For example, here's a change:

```
logliks <- lapply(1:3, function(X) {
  log(w[X]) +  dnorm(y, x[X], sigma[X], log = TRUE)
 })
```

Now, to evaluate expressions like `probs1`, you want to divide numerator and denominator by the biggest of the `liks` values, i.e. compute

```
(liks[[1]]/biggest)/(liks[[1]]/biggest + liks[[2]]/biggest + liks[[3]]/biggest)
```

but do it all on the log scale:

```
logbiggest <- max(as.numeric(logliks))
logprobs1 <- (logliks[[1]] - logbiggest) - 
  log( exp( logliks[[1]] - logbiggest ) 
    + exp(logliks[[2]] - logbiggest) 
    + exp(logliks[[3]] - logbiggest) )
```

and similarly for `logprobs2` and `logprobs3`.  Since `logbiggest` is equal to one of the `logliks`, one of those exponentials will equal 1.0, and then it doesn't matter if the other ones underflow.

Edited to add:  numerical example

You added data to your question.  Here is the full calculation using your data.  I don't get any zero probabilities, but most of them are very small:

```r
x <- c(0.7323412910, 0.7742235621, 0.4863889347)
w <- c(0.008464, 0.083536, 0.908000)
sigma <- c(0.08209500030, 0.08166088502, 0.09168991045)

y <- c(4.667935371,  5.654500961,  4.383309364,  4.396201611,  4.452524185,  4.441100597,  4.890487194,  4.416962624,  5.241273880,  4.347382069,  4.867616177,  4.895996094,  4.592288494, -3.612523079,  4.817468166,  4.783963203,  4.541391850,  4.709537983,  5.227987289,  5.585811138,  4.497674942,  4.989979267,  4.489729881)

probs <- matrix(NA, length(y), 3)

for (i in seq_along(y)) {
  logliks <- lapply(1:3, function(X) {
    log(w[X]) +  dnorm(y[i], x[X], sigma[X], log = TRUE)
  })
  
  logbiggest <- max(as.numeric(logliks))
  
  logprobs1 <- (logliks[[1]] - logbiggest) - 
    log( exp( logliks[[1]] - logbiggest ) 
         + exp(logliks[[2]] - logbiggest) 
         + exp(logliks[[3]] - logbiggest) )
  
  logprobs2 <- (logliks[[2]] - logbiggest) - 
    log( exp( logliks[[1]] - logbiggest ) 
         + exp(logliks[[2]] - logbiggest) 
         + exp(logliks[[3]] - logbiggest) )
  
  logprobs3 <- (logliks[[3]] - logbiggest) - 
    log( exp( logliks[[1]] - logbiggest ) 
         + exp(logliks[[2]] - logbiggest) 
         + exp(logliks[[3]] - logbiggest) )
  
  probs[i, ] <- exp(c(logprobs1, logprobs2, logprobs3))
}

head(probs)
#>              [,1]         [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 4.006975e-50 9.059815e-44    1
#> [2,] 1.964023e-93 2.172199e-87    1
#> [3,] 6.103586e-40 1.274113e-33    1
#> [4,] 2.221979e-40 4.668064e-34    1
#> [5,] 2.538854e-42 5.467829e-36    1
#> [6,] 6.336084e-42 1.358276e-35    1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The last one is equal to 1 because of rounding; the others are very small numbers.  This makes sense, because the `y` values are so much larger than the means, and the 3rd distribution has the largest variance:  so the model predicts that all those outliers are likely drawn from that distribution.  Multiply `sigma` by 10 and you'll get less extreme probabilities.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I am still trying to implement it correctly. As of yet, it still seems to be producing rows where prob1, prob2, and prob3 are all equal to zero. This then causes an error in the sample() function.

Comment: You should put a numerical example of one of those into your question.  Just show us `w`, `x`, `y` and `sigma`.

Comment: I added a numerical example with values your log-code gives 0's for. Hopefully this clarifies things. Agains thank you for the help. Also, I added the following three lines to your code to reverse back to non-log scale. I hope that makes sense:   probs1 <- exp(logprobs1)
  probs2 <- exp(logprobs2)
  probs3 <- exp(logprobs3)

Comment: Thank you, my code must have contained a mistake. When I run yours, I don't generate any rows with only zeroes anymore. One last thing: are you sure about the "max(as.numeric(logliks))"? My understanding is that you want the biggest log-likelihood per row. Wouldn't the max() function get larges value of the entire list?

Comment: In my loop, it is only taking the max of 3 values.  If you rearrange it to compute all of them in a dataframe, then you do need to take the row-wise max.

Comment: BTW, doing this in a matrix or dataframe would make a lot of sense:  most of the calculations are vectorizable.

Comment: Right, I see it now. In your loop the result is exactly what I want. Maybe using the built in vectorization of R can make it faster. I will look into it if I need my code to actually speed up. Thanks again for your input. Have a good night!

Comment: Hi, For the code I am adapting I need to tackle a similar issue to this. Now I am calculating a product of a large number (say a million) of probabilities. Eventually this rounds to zero again. Looking again at the method you sketched I was wondering the following: Why do we use the maximum value and not the minimum value? All values are in (-Inf, 0). The closer the original probability to 1, the close the log will be to 0. Wouldn't it be sensible to use the most-negative value to constrain the intermediate sum? Figured I'd ask you agian as your previous solution worked very well @user2254330

Comment: I used the max because in a sum, all I care about is that at least one value is in range.  The others can underflow to zero and it doesn't matter.  If I had used the min, the sum could have overflowed if there was one very small value that was used as the denominator.  For your product of probabilities, you don't need this trick.  Just sum the logs of everything.

Comment: I was thinking I do actually need the trick. When I perform the computation on the log-sum scale, I get a negative log-likelihood of approximately -860,000. That's still on only a fraction of the data. Taking exp(-860,000) I again get an underflowing value. If I somehow constrain this summed log-likelihood, I can perhaps avoid the underlow.

Comment: If those are actually probabilities that you are multiplying they are all 1 or less, so it makes sense that the product underflows.